# Conditional VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have to lookup values in a table which isn't in order (and can't order it) where I lookup a number which may or may not be repeated, but I need to bring the data of a specific one.

The data table is more or less like this:

```
 SAP Number   Multiple data columns   State
 123456       Whatever1               Finished
 111111       Whatever1               Finished
 123456       Whatever3               Blank
 123456       Whatever2               Finished
 111111       Whatever2               Blank
 111111       Whatever3               Finished
```

So I need to automatize part of a report table bringing data from the columns corresponding to each of the numbers that are in process (that I input manually by filtering and ordering according to a specific criteria)

The problem is, a simple lookup would return the first value, modifiying it to bring the last would not be effective because of the way the table is ordered.

I tried a matricial formula, but doesn't work (Notice that in spanish we have to use ";" instead of ",")

```
=+INDEX('Data Table'!R:R;MATCH(C27&"";'Data Table'!C:C&'Data Table'!AB:AB;0);1)
```

This should Lookup the SAP Num. in column C and a blank in column AB and bring the data from row R, but all I get is #N/A

Comment: Have you tried using pivot tables? These offer a different range of options for transposing your data, often leading to the required information.

Comment: I use pivot tables but in this one in particular is a table that is shared with other people that input the priority of the works in process and the data is arranged by this priority, I believe I can't input data manually into pivot tables and use it to sort the displayed values, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will have to be an array formula for a two column match.

```
=INDEX('Data Table'!R:R; MATCH(1; ('Data Table'!C:C=C27)*('Data Table'!AB:AB=""); 0); 1)
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum.

Comment: Great, it works, I solved it using VLOOKUP in matricial form, but it is very similar:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4;IF('Data Table'!$AB$10:$AB$2000="";'Data Table'!$B$10:$AB$2000;"");17;FALSE);VLOOKUP(C4;IF('Data Table'!$AB$10:$AB$2000="";'Data Table'!$C$10:$AB$2000;"");16;FALSE))
Is one of the columns I ended up with. In this case, it looks up numbers in two different columns, thats why the duplicate formula.